# jQuery add/remove css class on selected radio

Tags: jquery-ui

I've read a few solutions on here, but my problem differs enough where those will not work. Basically if the radio button is checked, add a css class to the parent div. If the radio is not checked, remove the css class. Sounds simple?

I have more than one radio button group, so in other words, there will be multiple radio buttons selected at a time. Each radio button group also is on different parts of the page seperated by other html.

Here is what I came up with:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').click(function () {
        if ($('input:not(:checked)')) {
            $('div').removeClass('style1');
        }
        if ($('input').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('style1');
        }


    });
});
```

I think I'm on the right path with the input:not(:checked), but on the next line it removes style1 from all div elements instead of checking if other divs radio button child is checked.

I guess what I'm asking is how do I write a script that when a radio button is clicked, add a css class to the parent and then find all div tags on the page that have a child of input. If the divs child input is not checked, remove the css class. So if a div has a child input element and it is checked, don't remove the css class from the inputs div.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not using the following: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2bzT/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').click(function () {
        $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("style1");
        $('input:checked').parent().addClass("style1");
    });    
});​
```

Comment: a year later..it still helped someone

Comment: Works fine, but the code seems to have an illegal character in it though. It's easily removed with a fiddle (marked in red): https://jsfiddle.net/y5hkookq/

Comment: There's also the fact that the classes are lost when the page is being refreshed, eventhough the options are still checked.

Comment: Btw: if it may help anyone: I'm using an `opacity: 0` on the input field itself (within the parent) so I can use background-images as check-states.

Comment: FYI If I copy this directly I get an error in my editor. If I copy/paste into this site. https://www.diffchecker.com/diff I can see a red dot after the last semicolon. But I could not see the character in my editor.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your radio buttons utilize the `name` property to properly group them, when one changes, you can find the radios with the same name, and remove the class, then add the class to the one that was activated.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/U2AAQ/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio').change(function () {
        $(':radio[name=' + this.name + ']').parent().removeClass('style1');
        $(this).parent().addClass('style1');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I needed to target the radio button's `label` instead of a parent `div` element.  I also needed to make sure the other related `label` elements did not have the class.

Here's what I came up with based on @user113716's answer:

**HTML**

> MVC code removed so there is only HTML in this example

```
<ol class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="choice_ChoiceId" class="form-control">ChoiceDescription</label>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="radio" id="choice_ChoiceId" value="choiceValue" name="choiceName" required />
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(':radio').click(function () {
    var _groupName = $(this).attr('name'),
        _radioId = $(this).attr('id'),
        _radioGroup = $(':radio[name="' + _groupName + '"]');

    //remove class from all labels for this group of radio buttons
    _radioGroup.each(function(){
        $('label[for*="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').removeClass('style1');
    });

    //add the class to the selected radio button
    $('label[for*="' + _radioId + '"]').addClass('style1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

```
'use strict';
var o = 'label.input-check, label.input-radio';
$(o).find('input').change(function () {
    $(o).find('input').filter('input[name="' + (this).name + '"]').each(function () {
        $(this).parent(o).toggleClass('checked', (this).checked);
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/3uwp9c2n/

Just optimize if you need.