# jQuery addClass if radio button checked

Tags: jquery, radio-button, parent, checked

Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(
        $("input.check").is(":checked")){
            $(this).parent().addClass("question-box-active");
    }
});
```

I'm trying to add a class (question-box-active) to the parent of .check (a radio button) only if it is checked. It works fine if I test with an alert, but I can't manage to add that class.

Thanks all for the help.

Update: This is the HTML for the form. I copied only 3 divs out of the 48. As you may have guesses I'm trying to add a class to question-box if the radio button is already checked on page load. So far no luck.

```
<div class="question-box">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" name="question-1" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['question-1'])) echo "checked"; ?> />
    <span class="question">1. Save a rainforest or grow organic vegetables</span>
</div>

<div class="question-box alt">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" name="question-2" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['question-2'])) echo "checked"; ?> />
    <span class="question">2. Solve complicated math problems</span>
</div>

<div class="question-box">
    <input class="check" type="checkbox" name="question-3" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['question-3'])) echo "checked"; ?> />
    <span class="question">3. Act in a movie, play, or television show</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
$('input.check').is(':checked').each(function() { 
    $(this).parent().addClass('question-box-active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `$(this)` is not referring to the radiobutton in your case

You could bind the click event of the radio button and decide what to do from there...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.check").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(this).parent().addClass("question-box-active");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kaveman. The form is set up so the page refreshes to display the results of the form after clicking submit. I already have a click function that adds the question-box-active class when the radio button is actively checked by the user. But when the page refreshed with the results, the class disappears even though the buttons are checked.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` you're using is within the function context of the `ready` handler callback, so it's not pointing to `input.check` as you expected.

Try something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var foo = $('input.check');

    if ( foo.is(':checked') ) {
        foo.parent().addClass('question-box-active');
    }

});
```

This is assuming your code logic is correct. I assume, however, that you're trying to do something similar to what Doug provided in another answer. Posting some HTML might help clarify.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your help. I added the HTML to my original question hoping this can help. I love jQuery but I'm not so good at it yet. I tried the code you provided, but the class was added to all parents even to those whose radio buttons were unchecked. I'm still playing around with it to see if I can dig something out, but please if you have any other ideas, let me know. It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var foo = $('input.check:checked');

    if ( foo.is(':checked') ) {
        foo.parent().addClass('question-box-active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually found the checked radio button rather than just checking to see if there was an input checked on the page. This allowed me to apply a class on the checked radio button.

Comment: I find this code more satisfying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376412/jquery-add-remove-css-class-on-selected-radio#answer-3376557